# How to count the nth occurence (position) of a character in a string?

Tags: string, vb.net, winforms, character

I am trying to make a hangman game using vb.net winforms (for a school project) and I want to know how to figure out the nth position of a characters occurence in a string.

```
dim randomstring as string = "stackoverflow"
 For int As Integer = 0 To randomstring.Length - 1
        Label2.Text &= "_  "
    Next
```

if I want to find the occurence of "o" in randomstring, I would want the output to be "6, 12", and then i would replace the underscores from label2.text with the o in those specific locations. Is there any way of doing this or even a better way of doing this?

Comment: You would call IndexOf in a loop. It allows you to specify a start index so you'd start at 0 the first time, then the index after the last match thereafter, until no match is found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of specific string in long text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615040/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-specific-string-in-long-text)

Comment: @jmcilhinney , how would you do that? Everywhere i've looked at indexof loops, they are talking about a list of strings, and I will edit my question above to show you how i determine my word

Comment: @41686d6564 , no it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET arrays begin with index 0. A `String` is an array of `Char`. This is how `IndexOf` can work and how we can loop through a String character by character. The String is treated as an array.

```
'To find the first index
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."
    Dim i = s.IndexOf("o")
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString)
End Sub

'To find index of all occurances
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim s = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
    For Each c In s
        If c = "o" Then
            lst.Add(i)
        End If
        i += 1
    Next
    'See what is in the list
    For Each item In lst
        Debug.Print(item.ToString)
    Next
    'Prints in Immediate Window
    '12
    '17
    '27
    '42
End Sub
```